# Creating custom alias analyses with LLVM 3.8

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm currently porting a project from LLVM 3.7 to LLVM 3.8 RC2. The 3.8 release scraps the old analysis group design and introduces a new model for alias analyses.

My program implements two old-style AA passes that I've converted to `AAResult` subclasses. It also uses the legacy pass infrastructure, because it seems that the new one isn't ready yet.

However, for out-of-tree users like myself, the new AA model doesn't play super nice with the legacy pass infrastructure. `AAResultWrapperPass` has a [hard-coded list of AA passes](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/AliasAnalysis_8cpp_source.html#l00449) that can be extended using `ExternalAAWrapperPass`.

[The first AA pass only implements aliasing queries](https://github.com/zneak/fcd/blob/llvm-3.8/fcd/pass_regaa.cpp#L61). It uses higher-level knowledge of how my project generates IR to tell when two pointers can't possibly alias.

The second and more complex AA pass, which is used after the code has already been optimized to some extent (benefiting from the first pass), only implements ModRef queries. [It uses `MemorySSA`](https://github.com/zneak/fcd/blob/llvm-3.8/fcd/callconv/x86_64_systemv.cpp#L259) (brought over from the development branch into my project) and thus needs the result of previous alias analyses to work.

The suggested strategy for an `ExternalAAWrapperPass` callback is outlined in unittests/Analysis/AliasAnalysisTest.cpp:

```
  PM.add(createExternalAAWrapperPass([](Pass &P, Function &, AAResults &AAR) {
    if (auto *WrapperPass = P.getAnalysisIfAvailable<TestCustomAAWrapperPass>())
      AAR.addAAResult(WrapperPass->getResult());
  }));
```

However, I'm pretty sure that there can be only one ExternalAAWrapperPass in the pipeline, and the problem is that I need one after my first AA pass (so that the second AA pass will pick it up), and another one after my second AA pass (so that the other passes will pick it up).

So how can I port two AA passes to LLVM 3.8 when the second pass depends on the first one?